# How does kbuild actually work?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild

When i'm developing a linux driver, i've read about how to write linux kbuild makefile through this [document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt)

I know kbuild system use makefile variables such as obj-y obj-m to determine what to build and how to build.

But what i'm confused about is where does kbuild system really execute build process.In a word, if i have `obj-m = a.o`, then where does kbuild system parse `obj-m` and execute `gcc a.c` ?

Comment: The answer is that make does all the work. The main kernel build makefile presumably has rules that use the `obj-m` and `obj-y` variables in appropriate places to hook those files up to appropriate build rules. (Posting as a comment because I don't know kbuild at all and so this is just based on general make behavior.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Kbuild's Makefiles aren't the easiest to read, but here's a high-level untangling (using the 4.0-rc3 kernel):

1. The top-level Makefile does

   ```
   include $(srctree)/scripts/Kbuild.include
   ```

   , where `$(srctree)` is the top-level kernel directory.
2. `Kbuild.include` defines various common stuff and helpers. Among these is `build`:

   ```
   ###
   # Shorthand for $(Q)$(MAKE) -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=
   # Usage:
   # $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=dir
   build := -f $(srctree)/scripts/Makefile.build obj
   ```

   `build` is used with a command like `$(MAKE) $(build)=dir` to perform the build for the directory `dir`. It makes use of `scripts/Makefile.build`.
3. Returning to the top-level Makefile, there's the following:

   ```
   $(vmlinux-dirs): prepare scripts
           $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$@
   ```

   `vmlinux-dirs` contains a list of subdirectories to build (*init*, *usr*, *kernel*, etc.). `$(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=<subdirectory>` will be run for each subdirectory.

   The rule above compiles object files for both the kernel image and modules. Further down in the top-level Makefile, there's some additional module-specific stuff:

   ```
   ifdef CONFIG_MODULES
   ...
   modules: $(vmlinux-dirs) $(if $(KBUILD_BUILTIN),vmlinux) modules.builtin
           # Do additional module-specific stuff using
           # scripts/Makefile.modpost among other things
           # (my comment).
           ...
   ...
   endif # CONFIG_MODULES
   ```
4. Looking into `scripts/Makefile.build` (the Makefile used by `$(build)`) now, it begins by initializing the `obj-*` lists and various other lists:

   ```
   # Init all relevant variables used in kbuild files so
   # 1) they have correct type
   # 2) they do not inherit any value from the environment
   obj-y :=
   obj-m :=
   lib-y :=
   lib-m :=
   ```

   A bit further down, it loads in the Kbuild file where `obj-y`, `obj-m`, etc., are set:

   ```
   include $(kbuild-file)
   ```

   Further down is the default rule, which has the `$(obj-y)` and `$(obj-m)` lists as prerequisites:

   ```
   __build: $(if $(KBUILD_BUILTIN),$(builtin-target) $(lib-target) $(extra-y)) \
            $(if $(KBUILD_MODULES),$(obj-m) $(modorder-target)) \
            $(subdir-ym) $(always)
           @:
   ```

   The `$(obj-y)` prerequisites come from `$(builtin-target)`, which is defined as follows:

   ```
   builtin-target := $(obj)/built-in.o
   ...
   $(builtin-target): $(obj-y) FORCE
           $(call if_changed,link_o_target)
   ```

   The actual building seems to be performed by the following rule:

   ```
   # Built-in and composite module parts
   $(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c $(recordmcount_source) FORCE
           $(call cmd,force_checksrc)
           $(call if_changed_rule,cc_o_c)
   ```

   `if_changed_rule` is from `Kbuild.include`. The rule ends up running the following commands in `Makefile.build`:

   ```
   define rule_cc_o_c
           $(call echo-cmd,checksrc) $(cmd_checksrc)                         \
           $(call echo-cmd,cc_o_c) $(cmd_cc_o_c);                            \
           ...
   endef
   ```

   `$(cmd_cc_o_c)` seems to be the actual compilation command. The usual definition (there are two possibilities in `Makefile.build`, AFAICS) seems to be the following:

   ```
   cmd_cc_o_c = $(CC) $(c_flags) -c -o $@ $<
   ```

   Unless set explicitly using e.g. `make CC=clang`, `CC` defaults to `gcc`, as can be seen here in the top-level Makefile:

   ```
   ifneq ($(CC),)
   ifeq ($(shell $(CC) -v 2>&1 | grep -c "clang version"), 1)
   COMPILER := clang
   else
   COMPILER := gcc
   endif
   export COMPILER
   endif
   ```

The way I untangled this was by doing a <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> during a kernel build and seeing where `make` reported the error. Another handy `make` debugging technique is to use `$(warning $(variable))` to print the value of `variable`.

Comment: This is cool debug method. Since` $(obj-y)` is only a list of `XXX.o`, how does `make` know where to find this `XXX.c` ? How does `make` actually get the path info?

Comment: @demonguy: The pattern rule `$(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c` takes care of it. `$(obj)` is the directory where the compiled object files will be placed, and `$(src)` is the directory where the sources are. The rule says that a file on the form `$(obj)/<name>.o` depends on a file on the form `$(src)/<name>.c` (where `<name>` is the same in both cases), and that you make the `.o` file from the `.c` file by running the recipe of the rule (the commands it contains).

Comment: but there are many different paths, for example `makefile` in `test1/1.c` contain `obj-y += 1.o` and `makefile` in `test2/2.c` contain `obj-y += 2.o`, then finally `obj-y` should be `1.o 2.o`. then how does `$(src)` handle different paths?

Comment: @demonguy: I haven't looked into it closely, but within each `Kbuild` file you're usually only dealing with a single directory I think. `build` spawns a separate `make` instance to run `Makefile.build` for each directory. (Calling `make` from within makefiles is called *recursive make* by the way.)